# Localisation of a binary product of categories

Tags: category-theory

Let $ C, D $ be categories. Let $ S, T $ be subclasses of the morphisms of $ C, D $ respectively (maybe containing identities). Then $$ C\times D [S \times T^{-1}] \cong C [S^{-1} ] \times D [T^{-1}] $$ via the canonical functor from the left to the right induced by the localisation.  This is not too hard to show if we use the explicit description of these categories with zigzag morphisms.  Is there a way to show it just using the universal property of localisation/products?

Comment: By zigzag morphisms, do you mean a calculus of fractions?  Not every localization admits such a description.

Comment: Didn't you get an answer to [this question at MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139020/is-the-localisation-of-a-product-of-categories-the-product-of-the-localisation) already?

Comment: I mean the standard way to construct the localisation,  which might end up in you leaving the universe/not getting a locally small category. I got an answer at MO but no proofs,  the linked answer to my question said this easy fact should follow from the UP, but I couldn't work it out

Comment: It does, but it's a bit complicated. The linked discussion at the nForum has more details: it's some manipulation of adjoints plus facts about reflectors of exponential ideals.

Comment: Ahh. I should have said that at the time I couldn't get the nLab page to load so I missed the discussion there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be a test category. There are natural isomorphisms of categories

$\phantom{~~~} \hom(C[S^{-1}] \times D[T^{-1}],E)$

$\cong \hom(C[S^{-1}],\hom(D[T^{-1}],E))$

$\cong \{F \in \hom(C,\hom(D[T^{-1}],E)) : F(S) \subseteq \mathrm{Iso}(\hom(D[T^{-1}],E))\}$

$\cong \{F \in \hom(D[T^{-1}],\hom(C,E)) : F(D[T^{-1}])(S) \subseteq \mathrm{Iso}(E)\}$

$\cong \{F \in \hom(D,\hom(C,E)) : F(T) \subseteq \mathrm{Iso}(\hom(C,E)), \,F(D)(S) \subseteq \mathrm{Iso}(E)\}$

$=\{F \in \hom(C \times D,E) : F(C \times T) \subseteq \mathrm{Iso}(E),\, F(S \times D) \subseteq \mathrm{Iso}(E)\}$

$=\{F \in \hom(C \times D,E) : F(S \times T) \subseteq \mathrm{Iso}(E)\}$

$\cong \hom((C \times D)[(S \times T)^{-1}],E).$

The Yoneda Lemma implies that $C[S^{-1}] \times D[T^{-1}] \cong (C \times D)[(S \times T)^{-1}]$.

If necessary I will add more details.